# Reactjs webapp giving error only in Safari browser - 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ReactElementValidator.createElement.bind(null,type)'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, font-awesome

I have developed a react SPA and it works fine on all browsers except Safari. The error that I get in my console is attached as an image below.

Error comes from two files. One is from the font-awesome cdn link

and other comes from my bundle js which is created using the code

```
gulp.task("bundle", function () {
return browserify({
    entries: "./app/js/index.jsx",
    debug: true
}).transform(reactify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("bundle.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("app/"))

})
```

Any links why this issue is arising? Thanks in advance.

[image: Error console for Safari]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding polyfills for bind fixed the issue.

```
`if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
   Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
     if (typeof this !== 'function') {
         // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
        // internal IsCallable function
   throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
}

var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
    fToBind = this,
    fNOP    = function() {},
    fBound  = function() {
      return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
             ? this
             : oThis,
             aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };

if (this.prototype) {
  // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
  fNOP.prototype = this.prototype; 
}
fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

return fBound;
};
}
```

`

After fixing these, I got another error with REACT INTL, which works on all browsers except safari. So there is a polyfill available for that one also in their website.